# Capsule Collider Is not available in first person character settings in Unity 5

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm learning Unity 5 and I have made simple game scene which has a coin and I wrote a code to collect a coin by first person character and when he walks towards the coin. So I dragged and dropped my code into coin layer in Hierarchy but to make this feature available I need to check the little checkbox of **Is Trigger** at my **FPSController** settings at the right side. The problem is **Capsule Collider** is shown at all and I really don't know why! There MUST be a section which is called **Capsule Collider** with **Is Trigger** option under the **Audio Source**. But as you can see ,it's not there & I don't know how to find it..  [see my print screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1sDsE.png)

Comment: **The problem is Capsule Collider is shown at all** or The problem is **NOT** Capsule Collider is shown at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it does not display in your **Scene View**, Enable it in the **Gizmos** by clicking on it.

[image]

Then under Built-in Components, make sure that `Capsule Collider` is selected. It show now show in the Scene View.

If it is not in the Inspector or not attached to your FPS Controller,  add it by yourself.

Select the FPS Controller, Got to **Component**->**Physics**->**Capsule Collider**. You can then resize it.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the Capsule Collider into your character yourself. All you have to do is select your character, scroll down the Inspector panel, click add component, search for Capsule Collider and select it.